# Перегрузка метода

Tags: java

Имеется библиотечный класс, от него мы наследуемся и перегружаем одну функцию. Так же имеется объект изначального класса, для него нам нужно вызвать перегруженную функцию. Каким образом такое можно реализовать в java и возможно ли вообще?

Answer (score 1):

```
// а класс в котором вы перегружаете метод, Б - класс из либы
class A extends B
{
  // метод который перегружается
  public void doSomething(); 
}

class UsesLibraryMethod
{
  private B libraryUtil = null;

  public void setLibraryUtil (B l) {this.libraryUtil = l;}
  public B getLibraryUtil () {return this.libraryUtil;}
}

использование:
UsesLibraryMethod ulm = null;
...

// здесь у вас вызывается метод в зависимости от того какой класс вы подсунете
ulm.setLibraryUtil(new A()); // ulm.setLibraryUtil(new B()); - для стандартного

ulm.getLibraryUtil.doSomething ();
```

еще есть вариант с применением паттернов

```
class A extends B
{
   private B util = null;

   // передаем ссылку на существующий обьект либы
   public A(B util) {this.util = util;}

   // здесь идут все методы которые просто передают управление класу либы, напр:
   public void doSomething () {util.doSomething();}

  // а вот этот метод 'перегружен' (в принцыпе у нас все методы перегружены но это детали):
  public void doUsefull(String message) {
    // а вот тут мы добавили "дополнительный функционал"
    if (null != message && 0 != message.lenght())
    {
        util.doUsefull(message);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: А еще не забывать про аннотации при перегрузке ибо иногда можно "попасть" с этим делом, читаем [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/40158/robustness-прочность-в-java) и [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/41759/tricky-inheritance-хитрое-наследование).

Comment: проверку аннотаций и javadoc я всегда доверяю эклипсу, но в данном случае еод писался не в IDE

Comment: @jmu, аннотации может и не быть, она просто служит для указания IDE на определенные желаемые проверки. А так, для информации задавшему вопрос.